# mongoDB $all causes 100 cpu spin

Tags: php, mongodb

I'll try to describe my scenario:

Each document in the collection have an array of elements: `["element X", "element Y"...]`
The end user want to find the collections that have the best match to an array of elements he chooses. 
User element array: `["Element foo, element bar, element w"]`

What I did was to use $all in a query - starting from the original user array and all permutations after it (all n-1 element possibilities, all n-2 element possibilities etc...) until I get him 50 results

Of course I indexed the field of the array, and everything worked fine.

The thing is - I had a user who typed above 40 elements... This caused a slow query `"millis" : 125` according to profiling and than mongoDB is stuck on 100% CPU until restarted.
I keep seeing this query over and over until the restart.

So my question is divided into 2 questions:

1. Technical - Why is the query keeps retrying? OK - it was a hard and slow query, but can I stop it from needlessly retrying with configuration?
2. Algorithmic - anyone knows an elegant solution to the problem without limiting the user to number of elements in a search?

Code snippet: (PHP)

```
$combinations_array = $this->combinations($elements_array, $current_match_count);
foreach ($combinations_array as $combination) 
{
    $query = array( 'element.name' =>  array('$all' => $combination ) ) ;
    $cursor = $collection->find($query);
}
```

Where `combinations` is a  function that outputs all combinations with size of `$current_match_count`

Comment: How is the query being executed? Some code perhaps? It would seem unlikely that MongoDB is "retrying" the query. Something else seems to be doing this so that would be the place to look.

Comment: so why is the CPU stuck on 100%?

Comment: It sounds like exactly what you are saying. You see the same query over and over. That means something is re-ending it. You could copy the query content and issue it yourself to see if you can reproduce externally. But my bet is there is some code that is re-sending the query and this is not MongoDB doing it by itself.

Comment: @neil - tried the query from mongo shell - same thing. CPU was at 100% for about a minute before I restarted it
db.mycollection.find({"element.name" : {"$all" : [
"elem1", "elem2",... "elem43"]}})

Comment: I'm confused about the purpose of the loop here and what exactly is coming out of it. But putting that aside for now. You are saying there is the `$all` query with 43 elements in it. What is the average size of the arrays it is matching against? And how many documents in the collection are we talking about? Useful information  for your question for any chance of trying to reproduce.

Comment: @NeilLunn - you are totally right... question 2 is a bit too broad... 43 is too much, but I was looking for a way not to limit the user. The average element number is around 15-20, and I have ~500,000 documents. I was wondering if there is a quick "mongo way" to improve the situation

Comment: Which version of MongoDB is this? `$all` with 43 elements cannot possibly match an array with less elements than that. That is the intention at least and clarified for MongoDB 2.6. At least the documentation there shows you that the equivalent is to test every value inside an `$and` statement. Which is algorithmic to what you can actually try.

Comment: using mongo 2.6.1 - indeed you are right, I'm taking a different algorithmic approach regarding which sub-permutations to try in this case. Thanks for the discussion Neil :)